# SMTP Email PDF attachemnt Not showing in Outlook

Tags: c#, smtp

Outlook attachment not showing nor downloading, perfectly working on gmail below is the screenshot

[image]

**Below is my Code, tried with fielstream and direct attaching file with content Type but may be missing something else**

```
> MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
>                         msg.From = new MailAddress("info@onyxgroup.com.pk");
>                         
>                         msg.To.Add(email);
>                         
>                         msg.IsBodyHtml = false;
>                         msg.Body = "hah";
> 
>                         var inlinepdf = new LinkedResource(Server.MapPath("~/Invoices/Invoice.pdf"));
>                         inlinepdf.ContentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
> 
> 
>                        var inlineLogo = new LinkedResource(Server.MapPath("~/images/logo-default.png"));
>                        inlineLogo.ContentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
> 
>                         string body = string.Format(@"
>                             <p>Onyx International</p>
>                            <img src=""cid:{0}"" width=""100px""/>
>                            <p>www.onyxgroup.com.pk</p>", inlineLogo.ContentId);
> 
>                         var view = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, null, "text/html");
>                        view.LinkedResources.Add(inlineLogo);
>                         msg.AlternateViews.Add(view);
> 
>                         string attachmentPath = Server.MapPath("~/Invoices/Invoice.pdf");
>                         FileStream fs = new FileStream(attachmentPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
>                        
>                         
>                         Attachment a = new Attachment(fs, "Invoice.pdf", MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
>                         msg.Attachments.Add(a);
>                        
>                         msg.Subject = "Invoice | Onyx International";
>                         SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
>                         smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
>                         smtp.Port = 587;
>                         smtp.EnableSsl = true;
>                         smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("ahsan.sykov@gmail.com",
> "password");
>                         smtp.Send(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont't Know Why but its working fine in hotmail/outlook but not working with new outlook/live version.